# How to include a chart in a mail

Tags: php, laravel, graph, charts

I send a daily report with table data to a number of subcribers.
It would be nice to show the data in a chart or graph like a bar chart or a line chart.
However, most graph libraries like GraphJS use javascript and javascript does not run in mails, at least not in Gmail.

Javascript does not run on my server.

I tried to generate the image server side and found [goat1000's svggraph](https://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php).
It works, generates a nice svg, but unfortunately some mail clients like gmail do not display svg.

I'd like to avoid dependency on an external online svg to image converter.

Does anyone know a library to generate chart/graph images (gif, webp, png, ...) with native php or laravel?
Or a php svg to image converter?

jpGraph is a possibility, but that is expensive for the small community project I target.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Browsershot

https://github.com/spatie/browsershot

This may take an html template and produce an image file which you can them embed or attach to the email.

Comment: Nice, good idea, but I can't have the headless version of google chrome on my web (shared) server.

Answer (score 0):

The non-standard [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) php extension allows to convert many image formats, including svg.

It is as simple as:

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat('gif');
$gif = $image->getImageBlob();
```

On ubuntu, ImageMagick can be installed using `sudo apt install php-imagick`

SVG is disabled for security reasons in many installations. The list of supported formats can be seen in `phpinfo()`'s section `ImageMagick supported formats`. If SVG is missing, it can be enabled using `sudo apt install libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra`

On my shared webserver, imagick is available with SVG support ([Combell hosting](https://www.combell.com/nl/hosting/webhosting)).